# Flume Agent not Receiving Data but no Error

Tags: flume-ng, bigtop

I've got a problem with flume. I am trying to get into big data and hence am working with the tutorial from the 'for dummies' books. The other stuff so far has more or less worked, but there is some problem with the flume agent.

[Here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/log-data-with-flume-in-hdfs.html) is the tutorial I am working with.

When I do everything according to the tutorial, my terminal output will be as followed:

```
16/02/05 17:19:33 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [shaman]

16/02/05 17:19:33 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Creating channels

16/02/05 17:19:33 INFO channel.DefaultChannelFactory: Creating instance of channel in-mem_c1 type memory

16/02/05 17:19:33 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Created channel in-mem_c1

16/02/05 17:19:33 INFO source.DefaultSourceFactory: Creating instance of source netcat_s1, type netcat

16/02/05 17:19:33 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Channel in-mem_c1 connected to [netcat_s1]

16/02/05 17:19:33 INFO node.Application: Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{netcat_s1=EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.NetcatSource{name:netcat_s1,state:IDLE} }} sinkRunners:{} channels:{in-mem_c1=org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel{name: in-mem_c1}} }

16/02/05 17:19:33 INFO node.Application: Starting Channel in-mem_c1

16/02/05 17:19:34 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitored counter group for type: CHANNEL, name: in-mem_c1: Successfully registered new MBean.

16/02/05 17:19:34 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: CHANNEL, name: in-mem_c1 started

16/02/05 17:19:34 INFO node.Application: Starting Source netcat_s1

16/02/05 17:19:34 INFO source.NetcatSource: Source starting

16/02/05 17:19:34 INFO source.NetcatSource: Created 
serverSocket:sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl[/127.0.0.1:44444]
```

From there on it won't do anything anymore. It will just stand like this until I shut down the terminal.

I've tried to telnet the agent but the messages won't appear.

Any idea what went wront?

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial, it is putting the data in HDFS, please check in your HDFS dir.